# Django Model Based Contact Form not displaying on Template

Tags: django-models, django-forms, django-templates

I've been cracking my head trying to figure out why a Contact Form is not displaying on the 'contact.html' template. I'm using Django 1.10 with Python 2.7. I'm need of some guidance.

models.py

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.db import models

class ContactForm(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    email = models.EmailField(blank=True)
    message = models.TextField()
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.forms import ModelForm
from .models import ContactForm

class ContactForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = ContactForm
        fields = ['name', 'email', 'message']
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, render_to_response
from .forms import ContactForm, ReportItemForm, RegisterItemForm
from django.template.loader import get_template
from .models import ReportItem, RegisterItem, ContactForm

def contact(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = ContactForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            message = 'success'
            form.save()
        else:
            message = 'fail'
        return render(request, 'returnApp/contact.html', {'form': form},)
    else:
        return render(request, 'returnApp/contact.html', {'form': ContactForm()},)
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

app_name = 'returnApp'
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^contact/', views.contact, name='contact'),
]
```

contact.html

```
<div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3"> 
    {% if message %}
    {% endif %}
        <form role="form" action="" method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ form.as_p }}
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
        </form>
</div>
```

output

```
 <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3"> 

            <form role="form" action="" method="POST">
                <input type='hidden' name='csrfmiddlewaretoken' value='FpQ06fHpZTpMmweGuFlGd0I4euP6KEFU9lWhu7fRUdeKIWtobdG6ngTJUGUKWb9Q' />

                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
            </form>
    </div>
```

Comment: show us you url.py pls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem. I gave the contact form the same name in models.py and in forms.py and it was confusing Django.
Changed the form class definitions this way

forms.py

```
class ContactFormForm(ModelForm):
```

in views.py

```
from .forms import ContactFormForm
```